# Failed connect to telegram by telethon

Tags: python, connection, telegram, telethon

My code:

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient
import socks
import logging
api_id = 1234567
api_hash = 'my_api_hash'

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
client = TelegramClient('session_name5', api_id, api_hash, proxy=(socks.SOCKS5, "1.2.3.4", 8080, True))
client.start()

print(client.get_me().stringify())
```

I'm trying to connect to telegram via telethon. I use a server in the USA, but I always get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): 
>     File "C:/Users/nik/Desktop/krypto_bot/run.py", line 9, in 
>       sign_client = client.start()
>     File "C:\Users\nik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 132, in start
>       else self.loop.run_until_complete(coro)
>     File "C:\Users\nik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 484, in run_until_complete
>       return future.result()
>     File "C:\Users\nik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 139, in _start
>       await self.connect()
>     File "C:\Users\nik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\telegrambaseclient.py", line 445, in connect
>       proxy=self._proxy
>     File "C:\Users\nik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py", line 124, in connect
>       await self._connect()
>     File "C:\Users\nik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py", line 237, in _connect
>       raise ConnectionError('Connection to Telegram failed %d time(s)', self._retries)
>   ConnectionError: [Errno Connection to Telegram failed %d time(s)] 5

My logs:

```
DEBUG:asyncio:Using selector: SelectSelector
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connecting to 149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection attempt 1...
DEBUG:socks:Error connecting to SOCKS5 proxy 1.2.3.3:1080 due to: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера
```

Comment: Are you sure that proxy is accessable? I've just checked - it doesnt work for me.

Comment: I changed proxy to 45.91.10.76:30001, it's fully accessable, but now I get a such error:`DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection attempt 1...
WARNING:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Attempt 1 at connecting failed: GeneralProxyError: Socket error: 0x02: Connection not allowed by ruleset`

Comment: You have problems with proxy. Just google 0x02 Error: 0x02 - connection not allowed by ruleset - If the address you're trying to connect to is blacklisted on the server or requires authentication.